# Mongo findOne function for node does not return geometrty data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am having some trouble trying to get mongo to correctly return geometry data.

When I run `db.shapes_houses.findOne({ 'properties.IDENTIFCAT': '0373100000004063' }` function directly in the mongo shell I get the correct results I need:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576bfc6d669adc5c2556676b"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "IDENTIFCAT" : "0373100000004063",
        "VOETPRINT" : 62.423811
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    105719.1640625,
                    515371.03125
                ],
                [
                    105715.9921875,
                    515375.4375
                ],
                [
                    105722.84375,
                    515380.375
                ],
                [
                    105725.3359375,
                    515382.15625
                ],
                [
                    105728.5,
                    515377.75
                ],
                [
                    105726.015625,
                    515375.96875
                ],
                [
                    105719.1640625,
                    515371.03125
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

However when I run the `db.Object.findOne({ 'properties.IDENTIFCAT': '0373100000004063' }).exec()` through my node app I don't get any of the geometry data, only id, type and properties are returned.

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?? I am tearing my hair out over it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Mongoose? If so, can you show the schema?

Comment: Not using the mongoose dependency - just the mongo...

Comment: Can you specify _"I don't get any of the geometry data"_? Is the `geometry` property missing? Is it empty? Have you asserted that the `_id` of the document is the same as the one showing in the Mongo shell?

Comment: ^apologies for above after further investigation it turns out I am using mongoose-simpledb. As for your second question - geometry property is completely missing and, yes, the _id in both cases are identical

Comment: In that case: can you show the schema? :)

Comment: `exports.schema = {
       _id: String,
       type: String,
       properties: {
           IDENTIFCAT: String,
           VOETPRINT: Number
       },
       geometry: {
           type: String,
           coordinates: []
       }
   };`

Comment: You should read [this page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey). If you want to declare a property called `type`, there's some things to consider when using Mongoose. I don't know how they translate to `mongoose-simpledb`, though. With your schema, it may be that Mongoose expects that `geometry` is a String, and when it can't cast its actual type (`Object`) to string it gives up.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the `typekey` option to `exports.schema.geometry` as explained [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey).

Answer (score 1):

The `MongoDB driver` for `NodeJS` uses `callbacks` to process the results of queries see [reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOne)

Use it with callback like this, it should work

```
db.Object.findOne({ 'properties.IDENTIFCAT': '0373100000004063' },function(err,result){
  if(!err){
     console.log(result)
   }
})
```

Comment: If id, type and properties are returned, you could probably infer that _that_ isn't the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply but result still does not contain the geometry data that I need when I try this.